Max product of a sublist of a list in python
This image contains Question Sorry can't provide in text as it  can not be copy from the platform
enter image description here
This is what I tried
Test cases
I was Having Problem solving Test case 2 all others worked fine with this code as you can see, I have hard coded the answer for test case 2.
am I doing something wrong? is there an alternate way to solve the question

I will solve after one hour because I am suspecting you are giving some kind of test

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

is your test case 2 about max product as in image 1 or min product as in your code?(we can help your ocr your images, but first be clear in your question)

Proper handling of negative list elements is a bit tricky based on the list having an even or odd numer of negative items.

The question you linked mentions maxProduct and zero or positive integers. The code/test cases you linked feature minProduct and negative integers. Please fix this discrepancy. As for Test Case 2, in your code you only calculate products of sublists starting from l[0], so you'll never work on the [3, 5] sublist.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Your method is O(n^2) time complexity. You allocate space for subarrays during each iteration with a space complexity of O(n).
Secondly, it is almost not worth mentioning the fact you hard coded a test case, this is of course not correct as you mention.
Solution:
Dynamically track the maximum and minimum product at every position in the list with one iteration.
Maintain a max_product and min_product value, the min_product is needed as multiplying a negative number by a negative min_produt will result in a maximum product.
Maintain a global_max value, update it to store the max product found so far in array.
If the current number is negative you swap the max_product and min_product as a negative number will have an opposite effect on a positive.
class Solution:
    def maxProduct(self, nums):
        if not nums:
            return 0
        
        max_product = nums[0]
        min_product = nums[0]
        global_max = nums[0]
        
        for i in range(1, len(nums)):
            num = nums[i]
            
            if num < 0:
                max_product, min_product = min_product, max_product
            
            max_product = max(num, max_product * num)
            min_product = min(num, min_product * num)
            
            global_max = max(global_max, max_product)
        
        return 2 * global_max

This solution has a time complexity of O(n) as it loops over once. The space complexity is O(1) as we only store the max and min values.
Your test cases:
# Test Case 1
print(sol.maxProduct([5, 2, 1, 1]))  # Expected Output: 20

# Test Case 2
print(sol.maxProduct([2, -2, 3, 5])) # Expected Output: 30

# Test Case 3 (Hidden Test Case)
print(sol.maxProduct([22, 11, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,0, 1, 1, 3]))  # Expected Output: 3872

# Test Case 4 (Hidden Test Case)
print(sol.maxProduct([6, 6, 3, 3,34, 4, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]))  # Expected Output: 352512

# Test Case 5 (Hidden Test Case)
print(sol.maxProduct([2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3]))  # Expected Output: 576

Output:

20
30
3872
352512
576

Also, this is a relatively famous LeetCode question (with some changes), I remember solving this on a train.

Nice solution; that said, your description of OP's code is inaccurate. Parsing all sublists would be inefficient but would work; OP only parses (twice in addition) sublists from the start of the initial list, which is why test case 2 fails.

@Swifty You're right that OP's code focuses on subarrays starting from the first element. My point was to highlight the inefficiency, I don't believe I said their solution wouldn't work though.

Indeed, my point is precisely that their code doesn't work, because they didn't do (or didn't do it well) the brute force approach.
